# How to convert sass (scss) into json?

Tags: css, json, sass

I want to convert SASS (scss) into json format. I see some node.js libraries out there like these

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-json-export
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-to-json
3. https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON

I'm looking for something like that 3rd link but for sass. So if I had something like

```
div[data-type='foo'] {
    span {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

it would transform it into (this is just an example):

```
{
    "rules" : [
            {
                "name" : "div",
                "where" : "[data-type='foo']"
                "rules" : [],
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "span",
                        "rules" : {"color":"red"},
                        "children":[]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Does anyone know if this exists?

Thanks

Comment: That's interesting.  Just curious what's the purpose of converting to JSON.

Comment: There's probably a bunch of reasons, but for me, I will have 3rd party people develop sass files to use in my app, and I have some validation I want to enforce, and its a lot easier to do that when you can read json data.

Comment: Why can't you use 1 or 2? Is that not what you're looking for? Alternatively, you could use a library that converts SASS to CSS then use the CSSJSON and convert that.  https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/

Comment: #1 i have no idea what it's doing, it doesn't look like my example, #2 is for only variables, and doing sass to css first is last resort, but I just wanted to see if there was a direct sass to json.